# Python random number generator not working properly

Tags: python, button, tkinter, dice

```
outcomeG = "0"
outcomeB = "0"

def roll(outcomeG, outcomeB):

    outcomeG = random.randint(1, 6)
    outcomeB = random.randint(1, 5)
    return outcomeG, outcomeB

def goodDiceRoll():

    goodDiceOptions.destroy()

    global goodDiceRoll
    goodDiceRoll = tkinter.Tk()
    goodDiceRoll.title("Green Dice roll")

    lbloutcome = tkinter.Label(goodDiceRoll, text="Press roll")
    btnRollG = tkinter.Button(goodDiceRoll, text="Roll", command=roll(outcomeG, outcomeB))

    if outcomeG == "1":
        lbloutcome.config(text="Green 1")
        goodDiceRoll.update()
        f = open("Logs.txt", "a")
        ts = time.time()
        sttime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
        f.write(sttime + "Green 1")
        f.close()

    elif outcomeG == "2":
        lbloutcome.config(text="Green 2")
        goodDiceRoll.update()
        f = open("Logs.txt", "a")
        ts = time.time()
        sttime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
        f.write(sttime + "Green 2")
        f.close()
        #rest of code
```

This is some of my code that is suppose to let you roll a green dice or red dice and then put it in a file. **However when I press the roll button that i made, it is suppose to randomize a number from 1 to 6 and display it but what really happens is absolutely nothing. How can i fix this?** Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well where do you instruct it to do something?

Comment: Is this the entire code? If so you only have function definitions and you don't have any code that actually gets run.

Comment: Calling `roll` doesn't actually *do* anything visible. It picks two numbers, sure, but then it returns them to... what? Nothing updates the UI as a result.

Comment: nothing to return

Comment: No this is only a bit of my code.

Comment: Its suppose to change the Label text from "Press roll" to the number from the random number generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `roll(outcomeG, outcomeB)` then don't expect those two global variables to change. They will remain 0. This is because the (parameter) variables within `roll` are local to that function. Any assignment made to those variables will not affect the variables that were passed to the function.

If you then call `goodDiceRoll()` the `if` blocks will not be entered since the values of those variables are still 0, and by consequence nothing gets written to the file.

You can solve this by doing:

```
outcomeG, outcomeB = roll()
```

... and remove the parameters from the `roll` definition.

But, as you don't call `roll` that way, but pass a reference to it via:

```
btnRollG = tkinter.Button(goodDiceRoll, text="Roll", command=roll)
```

... you are forced into using global variables. So modify `roll` like this:

```
def roll():
    global outcomeG, outcomeB  
    outcomeG = random.randint(1, 6)
    outcomeB = random.randint(1, 5)
```

Make sure to *also* define them as such in `goodDiceRoll`.

Secondly, it is a really bad idea to assign to `goodDiceRoll`, which really destroys the previous value it had, i.e. the function you are in. This will make the function unreachable after the first invocation. Use a different variable name.

Comment: Where should i put 'outcomeG, outcomeB = roll()' ?

Comment: Where you had your call to `roll`. I suppose you called it right?

Comment: It comes up with an error if i do that: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'outcomeG' referenced before assignment

Comment: that would be an error about a line *inside* your function. Did you reference `outcomeG` there before assignment to it?

Comment: No at the top of my code I have assigned outcomeG and B to 0.

Comment: Well if you don't call `roll` then where do you *change* the values of `outcomeG` and `outcomeB`? If you don't change them, then indeed nothing will happen, since the `if` statements require the values to be 1 or 2. Also, if you don't call `roll`, then why have that function there in the first place?

Comment: I call roll on this line: btnRollG = tkinter.Button(goodDiceRoll, text="Roll", command=roll)

Comment: The if blocks aren't working but everything else is fine.

Comment: Did you debug ?

Comment: What did you debug? Which variables did you print, and where? What were their values?

Comment: The roll function works when i press the button. The if statements are the things that are not working so the window doesn't get updated when i press the button and the output is also not put in the file.

Comment: That is not what I meant with debugging. What is the value of `outcomeG` before the first `if`? Did you check it?

Comment: The value is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6, it depends on what number the randomizer picks.

Comment: Please put a `print(outcomeG)` just before the first `if`. Does it really print a 1, 2, ... or 6?

Answer (score 0):

If what you have posted is the entirety of your code, then it is unlikely that anything will be written, since you only include cases for the green dice rolling a "1" or a "2". Instead of using **if** statements to deal with different cases of rolls, you should instead do something like this:

```
    f = open("Logs.txt", "a")
    ts = time.time()
    sttime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
    f.write(sttime + "Green " + outcomeG + ",\n")
    f.write(sttime + "Blue " + outcomeB + "\n")
    f.close()
```

Also you need to make sure when you call the 'roll' function, you can access that data.